# Frozen on BIOS logo after the GRUB selection

Tags: kernel, nvidia, manjaro, freeze, amd

I have the following packages avaliable to update:

```
lib32-lcms2-2.16-1  lib32-libdrm-2.4.118-1  linux510-5.10.204-1
             linux510-nvidia-545.29.06-4  linux510-virtualbox-host-modules-7.0.12-7
             linux61-6.1.68-1  linux61-nvidia-545.29.06-8
             linux61-virtualbox-host-modules-7.0.12-13  netpbm-10.86.39-1
             python-prompt_toolkit-3.0.42-1  thin-provisioning-tools-1.0.9-2
             thunderbird-115.5.2-1  vivaldi-ffmpeg-codecs-120.0.6099.80-1
             wxwidgets-common-3.2.4-3  wxwidgets-gtk3-3.2.4-3  xorg-server-21.1.10-1
             xorg-server-common-21.1.10-1  zxing-cpp-2.2.1-1
```

Updating them results in the machine frozen on the bios logo after the grub selection. Timeshifting back to yesterday restated the machine functionality.  I coulnt not get to a tty to check what can be happening.

Info about my machine:

```
inxi -Fazy 
System:
  Kernel: 6.1.67-2-MANJARO arch: x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 13.2.1
    clocksource: tsc available: hpet,acpi_pm
    parameters: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.1-x86_64
    root=UUID=34e9c83c-58ee-4a25-bb00-b4fc7d03af25 rw quiet
    udev.log_priority=3
  Desktop: KDE Plasma v: 5.27.10 tk: Qt v: 5.15.11 wm: kwin_x11 vt: 2
    dm: SDDM Distro: Manjaro Linux base: Arch Linux
Machine:
  Type: Desktop System: ASUS product: N/A v: N/A serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: ASUSTeK model: TUF GAMING X670E-PLUS WIFI v: Rev 1.xx
    serial: <superuser required> UEFI: American Megatrends v: 1813
    date: 10/13/2023
CPU:
  Info: model: AMD Ryzen 7 7800X3D bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Zen 4 gen: 5
    level: v4 note: check built: 2022+ process: TSMC n5 (5nm) family: 0x19 (25)
    model-id: 0x61 (97) stepping: 2 microcode: 0xA601206
  Topology: cpus: 1x cores: 8 tpc: 2 threads: 16 smt: enabled cache:
    L1: 512 KiB desc: d-8x32 KiB; i-8x32 KiB L2: 8 MiB desc: 8x1024 KiB
    L3: 96 MiB desc: 1x96 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 3178 high: 4200 min/max: 3000/5049 boost: enabled
    scaling: driver: acpi-cpufreq governor: schedutil cores: 1: 4200 2: 3000
    3: 3000 4: 3000 5: 2874 6: 3000 7: 3000 8: 3000 9: 3000 10: 4200 11: 3000
    12: 3000 13: 3000 14: 3000 15: 3000 16: 3579 bogomips: 134188
  Flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 sse4a ssse3 svm
  Vulnerabilities:
  Type: gather_data_sampling status: Not affected
  Type: itlb_multihit status: Not affected
  Type: l1tf status: Not affected
  Type: mds status: Not affected
  Type: meltdown status: Not affected
  Type: mmio_stale_data status: Not affected
  Type: retbleed status: Not affected
  Type: spec_rstack_overflow mitigation: safe RET
  Type: spec_store_bypass mitigation: Speculative Store Bypass disabled via
    prctl
  Type: spectre_v1 mitigation: usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer
    sanitization
  Type: spectre_v2 mitigation: Retpolines, IBPB: conditional, IBRS_FW,
    STIBP: always-on, RSB filling, PBRSB-eIBRS: Not affected
  Type: srbds status: Not affected
  Type: tsx_async_abort status: Not affected
Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA GA106 [GeForce RTX 3060] vendor: eVga.com. driver: nvidia
    v: 545.29.06 alternate: nouveau,nvidia_drm non-free: 545.xx+ status: current
    (as of 2023-11; EOL~2026-12-xx) arch: Ampere code: GAxxx
    process: TSMC n7 (7nm) built: 2020-2023 pcie: gen: 4 speed: 16 GT/s
    lanes: 16 bus-ID: 01:00.0 chip-ID: 10de:2503 class-ID: 0300
  Device-2: AMD Raphael vendor: ASUSTeK driver: amdgpu v: kernel arch: RDNA-2
    code: Navi-2x process: TSMC n7 (7nm) built: 2020-22 pcie: gen: 4
    speed: 16 GT/s lanes: 16 ports: active: none empty: DP-1,HDMI-A-1
    bus-ID: 10:00.0 chip-ID: 1002:164e class-ID: 0300 temp: 37.0 C
  Device-3: Logitech Logitech Webcam C925e driver: snd-usb-audio,uvcvideo
    type: USB rev: 2.0 speed: 480 Mb/s lanes: 1 mode: 2.0 bus-ID: 1-2:2
    chip-ID: 046d:085b class-ID: 0102 serial: <filter>
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 21.1.9 compositor: kwin_x11 driver: X:
    loaded: nvidia gpu: nvidia,amdgpu display-ID: :0 screens: 1
  Screen-1: 0 s-res: 2560x1440 s-dpi: 108 s-size: 602x342mm (23.70x13.46")
    s-diag: 692mm (27.26")
  Monitor-1: DP-4 res: 2560x1440 dpi: 109 size: 597x336mm (23.5x13.23")
    diag: 685mm (26.97") modes: N/A
  API: EGL v: 1.5 hw: drv: nvidia drv: amd radeonsi platforms: device: 0
    drv: nvidia device: 1 drv: radeonsi device: 3 drv: swrast gbm:
    drv: kms_swrast surfaceless: drv: nvidia x11: drv: nvidia
    inactive: wayland,device-2
  API: OpenGL v: 4.6.0 compat-v: 4.5 vendor: nvidia mesa v: 545.29.06
    glx-v: 1.4 direct-render: yes renderer: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060/PCIe/SSE2
    memory: 11.72 GiB
  API: Vulkan v: 1.3.269 layers: 5 device: 0 type: discrete-gpu
    name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 driver: nvidia v: 545.29.06
    device-ID: 10de:2503 surfaces: xcb,xlib device: 1 type: integrated-gpu
    name: AMD Radeon Graphics (RADV RAPHAEL_MENDOCINO) driver: mesa radv
    v: 23.1.9-manjaro1.1 device-ID: 1002:164e surfaces: xcb,xlib
Audio:
  Device-1: NVIDIA GA106 High Definition Audio vendor: eVga.com.
    driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel pcie: gen: 4 speed: 16 GT/s lanes: 16
    bus-ID: 01:00.1 chip-ID: 10de:228e class-ID: 0403
  Device-2: AMD Rembrandt Radeon High Definition Audio vendor: ASUSTeK
    driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel pcie: gen: 4 speed: 16 GT/s lanes: 16
    bus-ID: 10:00.1 chip-ID: 1002:1640 class-ID: 0403
  Device-3: AMD Family 17h/19h HD Audio vendor: ASUSTeK driver: snd_hda_intel
    v: kernel pcie: gen: 4 speed: 16 GT/s lanes: 16 bus-ID: 10:00.6
    chip-ID: 1022:15e3 class-ID: 0403
  Device-4: Logitech Logitech Webcam C925e driver: snd-usb-audio,uvcvideo
    type: USB rev: 2.0 speed: 480 Mb/s lanes: 1 mode: 2.0 bus-ID: 1-2:2
    chip-ID: 046d:085b class-ID: 0102 serial: <filter>
  API: ALSA v: k6.1.67-2-MANJARO status: kernel-api with: aoss
    type: oss-emulator tools: alsactl,alsamixer,amixer
  Server-1: JACK v: 1.9.22 status: off tools: N/A
  Server-2: PipeWire v: 1.0.0 status: off with: pipewire-media-session
    status: active tools: pw-cli
  Server-3: PulseAudio v: 16.1 status: active with: pulseaudio-alsa
    type: plugin tools: pacat,pactl
Network:
  Device-1: Realtek RTL8125 2.5GbE vendor: ASUSTeK driver: r8169 v: kernel
    pcie: gen: 2 speed: 5 GT/s lanes: 1 port: e000 bus-ID: 09:00.0
    chip-ID: 10ec:8125 class-ID: 0200
  IF: eno1 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter>
  Device-2: MEDIATEK MT7922 802.11ax PCI Express Wireless Network Adapter
    vendor: Foxconn driver: mt7921e v: kernel pcie: gen: 2 speed: 5 GT/s lanes: 1
    bus-ID: 0a:00.0 chip-ID: 14c3:0616 class-ID: 0280
  IF: wlp10s0 state: up mac: <filter>
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: Foxconn / Hon Hai Wireless_Device driver: btusb v: 0.8 type: USB
    rev: 2.1 speed: 480 Mb/s lanes: 1 mode: 2.0 bus-ID: 3-2:2 chip-ID: 0489:e0e2
    class-ID: e001 serial: <filter>
  Report: btmgmt ID: hci0 rfk-id: 0 state: up address: <filter> bt-v: 5.2
    lmp-v: 11 status: discoverable: no pairing: no class-ID: 7c0104
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 3.09 TiB used: 302.45 GiB (9.5%)
  SMART Message: Unable to run smartctl. Root privileges required.
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 maj-min: 259:0 vendor: Samsung model: SSD 980 1TB
    size: 931.51 GiB block-size: physical: 512 B logical: 512 B speed: 31.6 Gb/s
    lanes: 4 tech: SSD serial: <filter> fw-rev: 2B4QFXO7 temp: 34.9 C
    scheme: GPT
  ID-2: /dev/sda maj-min: 8:0 vendor: Kingston model: SA400S37480G
    size: 447.13 GiB block-size: physical: 512 B logical: 512 B speed: 6.0 Gb/s
    tech: SSD serial: <filter> fw-rev: 0102 temp: 35 C scheme: GPT
  ID-3: /dev/sdb maj-min: 8:16 vendor: A-Data model: SU630 size: 447.13 GiB
    block-size: physical: 512 B logical: 512 B speed: 6.0 Gb/s tech: SSD
    serial: <filter> fw-rev: 4c12 temp: 35 C scheme: GPT
  ID-4: /dev/sdc maj-min: 8:32 vendor: Kingston model: SA400S37480G
    size: 447.13 GiB block-size: physical: 512 B logical: 512 B speed: 6.0 Gb/s
    tech: SSD serial: <filter> fw-rev: KB.3 temp: 26 C scheme: GPT
  ID-5: /dev/sdd maj-min: 8:48 vendor: Kingston model: SA400S37960G
    size: 894.25 GiB block-size: physical: 512 B logical: 512 B speed: 6.0 Gb/s
    tech: SSD serial: <filter> fw-rev: Z1.3 temp: 26 C scheme: GPT
Partition:
  ID-1: / raw-size: 931.22 GiB size: 915.53 GiB (98.32%)
    used: 250.45 GiB (27.4%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/nvme0n1p2 maj-min: 259:2
  ID-2: /boot/efi raw-size: 188.1 MiB size: 183.4 MiB (97.51%)
    used: 37 MiB (20.1%) fs: vfat dev: /dev/sdd2 maj-min: 8:50
Swap:
  Kernel: swappiness: 60 (default) cache-pressure: 100 (default) zswap: yes
    compressor: zstd max-pool: 20%
  ID-1: swap-1 type: file size: 512 MiB used: 26.8 MiB (5.2%) priority: -2
    file: /swapfile
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 46.0 C mobo: N/A
  Fan Speeds (rpm): N/A
  GPU: device: nvidia screen: :0.0 temp: 53 C fan: 0% device: amdgpu
    temp: 36.0 C
Info:
  Processes: 395 Uptime: 5m wakeups: 0 Memory: total: 32 GiB note: est.
  available: 30.57 GiB used: 3.12 GiB (10.2%) Init: systemd v: 254
  default: graphical tool: systemctl Compilers: gcc: 13.2.1 alt: 11/12
  clang: 16.0.6 Packages: 2212 pm: pacman pkgs: 2201 libs: 519
  tools: pamac,paru,yay pm: flatpak pkgs: 11 Shell: Bash v: 5.2.21
  running-in: konsole inxi: 3.3.31
```

mhwd -li

```
> Installed PCI configs:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                  NAME               VERSION          FREEDRIVER           TYPE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          video-nvidia            2023.03.23               false            PCI
           video-linux            2018.05.04                true            PCI
```

Then I tried to use   video-hybrid-amd-nvidia-prime adding
MODULES=(amdgpu nvidia nvidia_drm nvidia_uvm nvidia_modeset)
to /etc/mkinitcpio.conf and rebuild the modules.

In all cases I get a frozen screen after the motherboard post.

It is worth mentioning that I changed the motherboard and processor some time ago and just rebuild the microcode from the processor so this might be related.

Comment: what does `rebuild the microcode from the processor` mean?

Comment: @joramanda x https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/microcode

Comment: that's nice - but that article doesn't contain the word "build", let alone rebuild, nor does it explain how you build the microcode FROM the processor

Comment: GRUB
From the article:
grub-mkconfig will automatically detect the microcode update and configure GRUB appropriately. After installing the microcode package, regenerate the GRUB configuration to activate loading the microcode update by running: 
# grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg

Comment: oh, LOAD microcode, that's not the same thing as ***rebuild** the microcode **from** the processor*